# Bot emulator-unable to debug

Tags: c#, botframework

I gave the correct AppId and Password. But still, I am getting this error
I also tried leaving a blank in place of AppId and Password. Any suggestions. I came across this issue several times in the past. But everytime time it worked magically after some time. Very inconsistent behavior.Any suggestions.

getting error

> [14:58:55]Cannot post activity. Unauthorized.
> [14:58:55]POST401directline/conversations//activities

[image]

Comment: try restarting the emulator?

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: it worked after I updated the emulator and restarted

Comment: @roney - Would you like to post that as an answer so you can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed an update notification on my emulator. I clicked on the notification, installed the update and restarted my emulator. Then it worked.